# Assign dynamic variable names to a list where each variable contains results

Tags: r

Context: I'd like to save the results of a Likelihood ratio test for a multinomial logistic regression in several dynamic variables, but I'm not sure how I could do that. This is what I've been trying:

```
library(lmtest)
indels = c("C.T","A.G","G.A","G.C","T.C","C.A","G.T","A.C","C.G","A.del","TAT.del","TCTGGTTTT.del","TACATG.del","GATTTC.del")


my_list = list()

for (i in 1:length(indels)) {
      assign(paste0("lrtest_results_",indels[i]), my_list[[i]]) = lrtest(multinom_model_completo, indels[i])
}
```

I was basically trying to save each variable (with the name lrtest_results_ + the dynamic part of the variable name which depends on the vector indels) in a list using the `assign` method and `paste0`, but it doesn't seem to be working. Any help is very welcome!

Comment: Use lapply: `my_list <- lapply(indels, function(i) lrtest(multinom_model_completo, i))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to `lapply` the test function to each element of the vector `indels` and assign the names after.

```
my_list <- lapply(indels, \(x) lrtest(multinom_model_completo, x))
names(my_list) <- paste0("lrtest_results_", indels)
```